# Math processing error

Tags: support, math-display

I keep getting math processing errors. I've tried force refreshing the page and clearing the browser cache and cookies and that doesn't seem to have done anything. Is there a site-wide issue with MathJax rendering right now, or am I the only person having this issue?

I've now tried this using the following OSs/browsers, hopefully confirming that this is not an issue on my end:

Latest Linux Mint: Firefox, Chrome, Opera
Mac OS X Snow Leopard: Chrome, Safari
Mac OS X Lion: Chrome

All of these show [Math Processing Error] for any MathJax equations.

Just so that no one thinks I'm yanking their chain, here are some images showing that MathJax works on math.stackexchange.com and doesn't work on stats.stackexchange.com.

[image: Working MathJax]
[image: Broken MathJax]

Comment: Seems to be a CV issue. math.stackexchange.com's MathJax works fine.

Comment: It seems to be working fine for me at the moment (Firefox and Safari on Mac OS X). I saw some intermittent problems earlier in the day, though. I've heard of similar problems on the math.SE site in the recent past. There may even be a meta thread there on it.

Comment: Yeah, I've looked there and I've tried everything they've said to do. Thanks though.

Comment: It works again, whoohoo!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The MathJax CDN was being updated from version 1.1a to version 2.0 yesterday and there was a glitch that prevented the old version from expiring properly, so there was a period of time when people were getting some files from version 1.1a and some from version 2.0, causing the math processing errors that you saw. If you were lucky, you got enough v2.0 files to process the page.

The issue was fully resolved about 8 hours ago (2:30AM EST), so if you are seeing further issues, try clearing your browser cache and reload the page. Some browsers may also need to be restarted to completely clear the cache.

Comment: PS, math.stackechange.com has been using the 2.0-beta copy of MathJax for several weeks, and so were not affected by the CDN problems, which only affected the mathjax/latest URL.